# Training Data Split across GPUs in DDP Pytorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

Goal: Train a model in Distriubted Data Parallel(DDP) setting using Pytorch Lightning Framework

Questions:

1. Training Data Partition: How is data partition across separate GPUs is handled with Pytorch Lightning? Am I supposed to manually partition the data or Pytorch lightning will take care of that?
2. Loss Averaging: Do I have to aggregate the losses myself or Pytorch Lightning is going automatically do that?

I have been spending time with the code-base of pytorch lightning, looking for how DDP sync is handled, but unable to find that exact code. Would appreciate a clarification on this.

Answer (score 3):

Lightning handles both of these scenarios for you out of the for you but it can be overridden. The code for this can be found in the official github [here](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/search?q=LightningDistributedDataParallel).